# Why does innerHTML inside a function get ignored when returning a value to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling a function that prints to a div , then returns a string which is also printed to a div. The following will only print "two", but I was expecting it to print "one" then "two":

```
<body>
     <div id="view"></div>
</body>
<script>
global_cdiv = "view"
function test1(){
    document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML += "one" + "<br>";
    return "two";
}
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML += test1();

</script>
```

No errors or anything show up in the debug.
Why does Javascript ignore the innerHTML inside the function?
(A work around would be to store the value from test1() into variable then printing it, but why can't test1 be used directly?)

Comment: At least you could put your `<script>` inside `<body>`, or in an `onload` in `<head>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML += test1();
```

is a short form of

```
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML = document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML + test1();
```

Before evaluating `test1()` the `innerHTML` value is evaluated which is empty and that is getting concatenated with the result of `test1()` which is `two`. So, the actual expression becomes like this

```
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML = "" + "two";
```

This overwrites whatever set inside `test1()`. Thats why you see only `two`.

To understand that it really overwrites it, change your `test1()` like this

```
function test1(){
    document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML += "one" + "<br>";
    console.log(document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML);
    return "two";
}
```

It will print `one<br>`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! ty for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1):

when you call `document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML += test1()` this is the order of execution:
1- evaluate `document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML` and save it into a temporary variable
2- execute `test1` function
3- append the temporary variable to the return of `test1` function
4- assign the result to `document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML`

so this is roughly what you're doing:

```
var temp = document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML = "one"  // inside your function
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML = temp + "two"
```

the second `innerHTML` (which is inside your function in your case) assignment get overwritten by the third one (not appended to "two")

Comment: Have `console.log(document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML)` inside `test1()` after the += statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
     <div id="view"></div>
</body>
<script>
global_cdiv = "view";
    var temp = ""; 
function test1(){
   temp = "one" + "<br>";
    return temp + "two";
}
document.getElementById(global_cdiv).innerHTML = test1();

</script>
```

Checkout the code above. This will solve your problem.